# How do you measure quiescent current?

Tags: current-measurement, quiescent

How do you measure quiescent current?
(For instance, a Battery connected device)

Comment: Could you provide a circuit? We have a built in circuit plugin tool where you can make a small circuit so that we can see what you're talking about. Where is the battery connected?

Comment: Roo - Can you be more specific about the problem? For example, is your problem about *physically* making the connection in series with the power source / battery? Or is it a *measurement* problem, and your existing equipment can't measure those low currents? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You measure it like you would active current use. Nothing changes. Quiescent current is the amount of current a circuit, that is doing nothing, takes. You would connect it to a ammeter just the same. For very low quiescent currents, you may need a more precise or quality meter. Some devices or circuits have IQs in the micro and nano amp ranges, which a cheaper meter would not be good enough to register properly.

Comment: Maybe I'll invest in a uCurrent